# How can I stop DiskUtilities from requesting permission every time I try to create an image from a CD

Tags: disk-utility, disk-image

I have a big stack of CDs from the 90s that I want to keep the data from, but don't want the physical CD anymore. So I'm using Disk Utility to create the disk images.

Every time I do (by right-clicking the volume in Disk Utility and clicking "Image from {volume name}"), I get this message:

[image: Confirmation Dialog]

The first time it happened, I figured it would be a one-time thing, but it happens *every* time. Googling the message results in no helpful information. How can I prevent it from asking for permission each time?

Running macOS 10.13.6, Disk Utility 17.0.3, using an Apple USB SuperDrive with a MacBook Pro 15" from 2016.

Comment: What type of CD's, Audio or Data and if the latter how were they written? In other words, if data, can the discs filesystem be viewed normally in Finder?

Comment: These are all data CDs (although some dual format, having an audio CD volume).

Comment: You really didn't answer completely what I asked in my previous comment, so let me rephrase. How were the discs created? What software created them, especially the discs that are dual formatted? Can the discs be viewed in Finder just like viewing files in your Home folder in Finder, including the audio portion of the disc?

Comment: I apologize. These are all commercial CD-ROMs. FileMaker Pro 6 Developer, The Cartoon History of the Universe, Mac OS X Snow Leopard. They all mount and are viewable in the Finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mac OS X Snow Leopard** is a **DVD** not a **CD** and I'd imagine some of the other *discs* you're trying to copy are **DVD**'s too. Anyway, I can replicate your situation however, I also can do it from **Disk Utility** without being prompted for my password.

To do that, first *unmount* the *disc* and then *select* the *parent node*, e.g. on my **Apple SuperDrive** it's **HL-DT-ST DVDRW GX40N**, and *option-click* (*right-click*) and *select*: **Image from HL-DT-ST DVDRW GX40N Media**

In the subsequent **dialog box** *change* **Save As:** to something more user friendly, and *change* **Format:** to: **DVD/CD master**

Click the **Save** button and the *disc* will then start coping without being prompted for your password.

When finished click the **Done** button.

You can mount then disc image by double-clicking on it in **Finder**.

---

The above instruction are for **Data DVD/CD** *discs*  not **Audio CD** *discs*. Also note that I do not have a **Hybrid Data DVD/CD/Audio CD** *disc* to test whether or not the method shown above will work with that kind of *disc*.

Comment: The drive doesn't show up unless there's a disk in it. When there is, it shows up as `HL-DT-ST DVDRW GX40N Media`, but if I eject the mounted disk, that disappears from the `External` section of the sidebar. The "View>Show All Devices" is checked in the menu bar.

Comment: @Chuck, I never said to eject the disc, I explicitly and specifically stated "_unmount_ the _disc_". Unmounting a disc is not the same as ejecting a disc and why there is an Unmount button in the Toolbar and an Unmount command in the File menu in Disk Utilities. There is also an Eject command in the File menu in Disk Utilities but it makes no sense ejecting a disc if one is going to first make a copy. Only after making the copy then one can eject the disc, so as to go onto the next one, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the distinction.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use Disk Utility to make a copy of a CD.  The reason you're seeing the password dialog is because Disk Utility accesses the "raw" disk device.  You don't need to do this to make a copy.

There are a number of "better" (and free) alternatives.

- [XLD - X Lossless Decoder](https://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html).  It's an *old* GUI app that hasn't been updated in about a year (at the time of this post), but it still works on  El Capitan, Sierra, and High Sierra.  It even has binaries for PowerPC based Macs.
- `dd` - a Terminal based utility that makes bit-for-bit copies of *any* type of CD.  Just use the command:

  ```
  $ dd if=/dev/diskX of=/path/to/image.iso
  ```

  Where X is the disk identifier of the CD/DVD drive and the `path/to/image.iso` is the location and file name of the disk you want to save
- [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) - A free library that included with many Audio/Video applications (i.e. [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php)).  You can use this in Terminal as well.  Just issue the command to get a lossless copy of the CD:

  ```
  $ ffmpeg -f libcdio -ss 0 -i /dev/diskx /path/to/image.flac
  ```

Again, where X is the disk identifier and the `/path/to/image.flac` is the location and filename of the CD image you want to create.

Comment: Several of these are for music - the OP questions seems to me to be about data CDs

Comment: @mark  - yes...it sounds like archiving audio CDs (given they were very prevelant in the 90s).  Two are for audio and one can be used for either data and audio (`dd`)

Comment: Don't forget that with `dd` the disc cannot be mounted or one gets the `dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy` error. Also, while `dd` can make an image of an Audio CD nonetheless, the resulting image is not natively mountable because macOS doesn't natively understand an Audio CD RAW Image and will get the error message: "The following disk images couldn't be opened" showing  "name.iso image not recognized". Normally with a Audio CD RAW Image one also needs to have a `.cue` file for each RAW Image and `dd` doesn't do that.

Comment: +1 for `dd`. Honestly, how to archive audio recordings should be an entirely separate question. As I read it, OP is only concerned with archiving the data, and they can burn an image to disk if they want the audio. +1